# Correct way to call functions "step by step"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have certain functionality that requires me to make one api call to retrieve certain id that is used in second api call, logic wise it would look like this:

```
componentWillMount () {
  this.props.functionOne()

  // Wait for functionOne to complete before calling this
  this.props.functionTwo(this.props.paramFromFunctionOne)
}
```

where `this.props.paramFromFunctionOne` is something stored in redux state once function one completes.

Comment: I haven't used react or redux, but I'm sure they have some way to use Promises.  Have you tried using either library's Promise implementation or even native Promises?

Comment: What `ajax` lib you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I correctly understand, you can achieve it this way:

```
componentWillMount () {
  // As `axios` returns promise, you should return it from `functionOne`
  // This way you can be able to use `.then` method.
  this.props.functionOne()
    .then(() => {
      // This code block would be executed after api call from first function will be finished.
      this.props.functionTwo(this.props.paramFromFunctionOne)
    });
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, have the `paramsFromFunctionOne` actually be a parameter in `then`.

Comment: @styfle, yes, it also possible.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) for that. Redux saga is specifically used for calling asynchronous functions and handling the side-effects.

For example, you may want to show a loader icon on your UI, while the data is being fetched. And subsequently hide the loader icon after you receive the data. You can write convert this asynchronous activity into a synchronous one using Redux-saga.

Example saga-

```
import { take, call, put, fork, cancel, race } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux';
import { DATA_LOAD_REQUEST } from './constants';
import { dataLoadSuccess, dataLoadFailure } from './actions';

import request from 'utils/request'; //isomorphic-fetch

export function* getCompanies() {
  const requestURL = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/32rap';
  const { companies, timeout } = yield race({
    companies: call(request, requestURL),
    timeout: call(delay, 10000),
  });

  if (companies) {
    yield put(dataLoadSuccess(companies.data));
  } else if (timeout) {
    yield put(dataLoadFailure());
  } else {
    yield put(dataLoadFailure());
  }
}

export function* getCompaniesWatcher() {
  while (yield take(DATA_LOAD_REQUEST)) {
    yield call(getCompanies);
  }
}

export function* companiesData() {
  const watcher = yield fork(getCompaniesWatcher);

  yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE);
  yield cancel(watcher);
}

// All sagas to be loaded
export default [
  companiesData,
];
```

You may find this mind-boggling, at first. Let me explain it bit by bit. If you ignore the redux-saga boilerplate, you can see that this code "looks" absolutely synchronous!

Deciphering the given code-

1. Dispatch `dataLoadRequest()` to the redux store. (To show loader on UI).
2. Request data to API.
3. Handle timeout (if data does not load in 10 seconds, dispatch `dataLoadFailure()` action to the redux store.
4. If data is received, dispatch `dataLoadSuccess()` action to the store.

Redux-saga uses ES6 generator functions. `yield` keyword is part of generator function. `function*` denotes that it is a generator function and not normal javascript function.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: `you can see that this code is absolutely synchronous!` it's not, it doesn't block the event queue -- much better after the edit :) I just didn't want the OP to think this was actually truly synchronous!

Comment: @Alex Edited. Thanks for pointing that out. What I meant is that redux-saga helps us to write asynchronous code in synchronous style. We don't need to use callbacks or promises. The code looks as if we're writing an algorithm in natural language. Hope you get the gist of the answer.